# How to make divs not shrink when window is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a notes page for my classmates as we return to school, and I have this flashcard-type UI that I'm using. I currently have 4 of the cards on the page, but I need to fit 7, and I would like it to scroll horizontally. I have already tried `x-overflow: scroll;` in CSS on the body, but it didn't seem to work. My code is attached to the fiddle below, please let me know how I can fix the horizontal scrolling problem.

In a general sense, I have 4 divs in a row that shrink the div size when the window resolution is changed. Changing the x-overflow property in css doesn't work, so is there a way so these divs will not shrink and will make the page scroll instead?

```js
var UID = {
    _current: 0,
    getNew: function(){
        this._current++;
        return this._current;
    }
};

HTMLElement.prototype.pseudoStyle = function(element,prop,value){
    var _this = this;
    var _sheetId = "pseudoStyles";
    var _head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var _sheet = document.getElementById(_sheetId) || document.createElement('style');
    _sheet.id = _sheetId;
    var className = "pseudoStyle" + UID.getNew();
    
    _this.className +=  " "+className; 
    
    _sheet.innerHTML += " ."+className+":"+element+"{"+prop+":"+value+"}";
    _head.appendChild(_sheet);
    return this;
};

var open = false;

function enlarge(box, header) {
    if (open) {
    open = false;
        
    header.style.top = "35%";
    header.style.fontSize = '4.5em';
        
    box.pseudoStyle("before","top","-50%");
    box.pseudoStyle("before", "transform", "skewY(345deg)");
    box.style.position = 'relative';
    box.style.width = '320px';
    box.style.height = '420px';
    box.style.zIndex = '1';
        
        
    document.getElementById("greything").style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
document.getElementById("greything").style.zIndex = '-1';
        
    } else {
    open = true;
   box.pseudoStyle("before","top","-70%");
    box.pseudoStyle("before", "transform", "skewY(390deg)");
    box.style.width = '640px';
    box.style.height = '840px';
    box.style.background = '#122936';
    box.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    box.style.zIndex = '4';

    
document.getElementById("greything").style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)";
 document.getElementById("greything").style.zIndex = '2';
    
    header.style.top = "10px";
    header.style.fontSize = '6em';
    }

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

.header {
    color: whitesmoke;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    top: 35%;
    transition: .5s;
}

#greything {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: 1s;
}

.card::before {
    z-index: 3;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2196f3;
    transform: skewY(345deg);
    transition: 1s;
}

.card {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 420px;
    background: #122936;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
    margin: 50px
}


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Poppins;
}

body{
   display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #09161d;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#notes {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    word-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
  border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 1s;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #2196f3; 
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>StudySmart Theme</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="card" id="science" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hS'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hS">Science</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card" id="math" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hM'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hM">Math</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card" id="history" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hH'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hH">History</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card" id="english" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hE'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hE">English</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div id="greything"></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I just edited the question and title, thanks for the help. @j08691

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add container. Look at this:

html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    //your body code
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Working example:

```js
var UID = {
    _current: 0,
    getNew: function(){
        this._current++;
        return this._current;
    }
};

HTMLElement.prototype.pseudoStyle = function(element,prop,value){
    var _this = this;
    var _sheetId = "pseudoStyles";
    var _head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var _sheet = document.getElementById(_sheetId) || document.createElement('style');
    _sheet.id = _sheetId;
    var className = "pseudoStyle" + UID.getNew();
    
    _this.className +=  " "+className; 
    
    _sheet.innerHTML += " ."+className+":"+element+"{"+prop+":"+value+"}";
    _head.appendChild(_sheet);
    return this;
};

var open = false;

function enlarge(box, header) {
    if (open) {
    open = false;
        
    header.style.top = "35%";
    header.style.fontSize = '4.5em';
        
    box.pseudoStyle("before","top","-50%");
    box.pseudoStyle("before", "transform", "skewY(345deg)");
    box.style.position = 'relative';
    box.style.width = '320px';
    box.style.height = '420px';
    box.style.zIndex = '1';
        
        
    document.getElementById("greything").style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
document.getElementById("greything").style.zIndex = '-1';
        
    } else {
    open = true;
   box.pseudoStyle("before","top","-70%");
    box.pseudoStyle("before", "transform", "skewY(390deg)");
    box.style.width = '640px';
    box.style.height = '840px';
    box.style.background = '#122936';
    box.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    box.style.zIndex = '4';

    
document.getElementById("greything").style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)";
 document.getElementById("greything").style.zIndex = '2';
    
    header.style.top = "10px";
    header.style.fontSize = '6em';
    }

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');

.container {
  
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header {
    color: whitesmoke;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    top: 35%;
    transition: .5s;
}

#greything {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: 1s;
}

.card::before {
    z-index: 3;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2196f3;
    transform: skewY(345deg);
    transition: 1s;
}

.card {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 420px;
    background: #122936;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
    margin: 50px
}


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Poppins;
}

body{
   display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #09161d;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#notes {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    word-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
  border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 1s;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #2196f3; 
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>StudySmart Theme</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card" id="science" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hS'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hS">Science</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card" id="math" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hM'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hM">Math</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card" id="history" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hH'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hH">History</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card" id="english" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hE'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hE">English</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div class="card" id="math" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hM'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hM">Math</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card" id="math" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hM'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hM">Math</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card" id="math" onclick="enlarge(this, document.getElementById('hM'))">
            <h1 class="header" id="hM">Math</h1>
        </div>
        
        <div id="greything"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: With `body { justify-content: left; }` or you wont be able to reach firsts items.